# Linear map from a cartesian product of two vector spaces implies existence of two linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to figure out this problem.

**Problem:** Identify $\mathbb{R}^{n+k} = \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^k$. Let $D: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a linear map. Prove that there exist unique linear maps $A: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and $B: \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $$ D(v,w) = A(v) + B(w)$$ for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^n $ and $w \in \mathbb{R}^k$.

**Attempt:** I'm having trouble defining these linear maps $A, B$ correctly. I first took $\beta = \left\{e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_{n+k} \right\}$ as the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^{n+k}$. Let $v= (v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ and $w = (w_1, \ldots, w_k)$. Then I have $$ v = \sum_{i=1}^{n} v_i e_i, \qquad w = \sum_{j=1}^{k} w_j e_j. $$ So then $$D(v,w) = D(\sum_{i=1}^{n} v_i e_i,\sum_{j=1}^{k} w_j e_j) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^k v_i w_j D(e_i, e_j) $$ by linearity. But now I don't know how to define the action of the linear map $D$ on the basis vectors. Should I just let $D(e_i, e_j) = A(e_i) + B(e_j)$ ?

Help with this problem is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need bases for defining $A$ and $B$; consider
$$
A(v)=D(v,0),\qquad B(w)=D(0,w)
$$